# How do I parse the custom html widget in cheerio?

Tags: html, jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape the data from a website using Axios and cheerio in nodejs but the problem is I couldn't get the desired value as the HTML is different here, The HTML is given below

> ```
> <div id="cars">
>     <new-chart-modal
>       :template-widgets-json='[{id: 1, Value: "10000"},{id: 2, Value: "20000"}]'
>       @close-widget-modal="closeWidgetModal"
>       @loaded-widget-template="loadedWidgetTemplate"
>       ref="newWidgetModal"    
>     >
>     </new-chart-modal>
>     <dashboard-grid
>       :widgets-json='[{id: 1, name: "Volvo"}, {id: 2, name: "BMW"}]'
>       @edit-in-tab="editWidgetInTab"
>       ref="grid"    
>     >
>     </dashboard-grid>
>   </div>
> ```

In the above HTML, I need to get the value of **:widgets-json** inside the dashboard-grid tag alone, but I'm unable to do it. I looking for some answers or tips to get the value of **:widgets-json** inside the  which is [{id: 1, name: "Volvo"}, {id: 2, name: "BMW"}]. can somebody please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a Vue template or similar, not HTML. Usually, templating languages are compiled down to HTML, so the actual HTML would be different. Which site is this, please, and can you share your code attempt so far? Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to scrape the indices stats data (First Table) from this website https://chartink.com/dashboard/4,

        const url = "https://chartink.com/dashboard/4";
        const headers = { "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,compress" }
        const pageData = await axios.get(url, { headers });        
        const $ = cheerio.load(pageData.data);
        const parentElem = `#root > div > div:nth-child(3) > div#atlas-grid-layout > div > div.v-cloak--hidden.flex.flex-col.leading-relaxed.flex-1 > `
        const tableElem = $(parentElem).html();        
        console.log(tableElem);

Comment: @ggorlen I cannot get the table data, I thought parsing it would solve the problem but it didn't. Do you have any idea how can I parse the table data? The problem is the API response doesn't have the stock data when I fetch it but it is actually there in website

Comment: Ah, I see that the template is in the static response and is then converted to basic HTML after the page loads and runs Vue on it. Glad you got it answered in any case. I know you found an answer, but you can [edit] your code into the question so it's a bit clearer for future visitors. Thanks.